# Can I transfer Devise users from one database to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I rebuilt my application from scratch, and in that process, I changed the database from MongoDB to PostgreSQL. I've got existing users who signed up via Devise on the MongoDB database and would like to transfer them to the PostgreSQL database, which is also using Devise.

Is this possible, and if so, how? From a preliminary test of creating users with the same email and password in each version of the application, the `encrypted_password` is different.

Comment: check http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql?view=asciicast or http://alistairisrael.wordpress.com/2007/09/07/using-rails-console-to-copy-records-across-databases/

Comment: @Mandeep Those solutions don't address the issue of password encryption. My guess is that I'd need to get access to the salt Devise is using so I can copy it over, but I'm not sure where Devise gets it.